# Why $(A - \lambda I)^{n} = 0$ where $n$ is the algebraic multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could someone please give me a formal proof of the statement in the title? My teacher told me that  it is analogous to a polynomial $q(x)*(x - \lambda)^n = 0$, where $(x - \lambda)^n = 0$. But this does not make sense to me. In the analogy, $(x - \lambda), (x - \lambda)^2, etc. $ will also be $0$, and at any rate the analogy is not necessarily rigorous.

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify a bit about the properties of $A$? In order for the statement to be true, $\lambda$ must be the unique eigenvalue of $A$. Do we take that to be the case?

Comment: This is a particular case of the more general [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: @HaydnGwyn Thanks! I don't recall my teacher did not mention a condition like that, but I may have been mistaken

Comment: TheSilverDoe's answer explains why the condition is necessary. The general Cayley-Hamilton theorem is not a straightforward result to prove. Generally speaking, if the eigenvalue $\lambda$ has algebraic multiplicity $m$, then there is a subspace of dimension $m$ that is killed by $(A-\lambda I)^m$. See [generalized eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector).